# advantage of npm mariasql over mysqljs

Tags: mysql, npm, mariadb, node-mysql, mariasql

i see that MariaDB has its own [npm package](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql).  is there any advantage(s)/disadvantage(s) of using this one over the older [mysqljs package](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)?

i would think the two could be used interchangeably, but that just a guess.

personally i have become a fan of [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/), but it appears sequelize may not have a pure "insert" option, only "upsert" which may not work for me.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: ultimately i am trying to figure out which node package is best to use with mariadb, since the two seem very similar, at least from a newbie viewpoint.   also, would a mysql person want to use the mariasql package?